# What is so great about TPL

Tags: multithreading, multicore, task-parallel-library

I have done this POC and verified that when you create 4 threads and run them on Quad core machine, all cores get busy - so, CLR is already scheduling threads on different cores effectively, so why the class TASK?

I agree Task simplifies the creation and use of threads, but apart from that what? Its just a wrapper around threads and threadpools right? Or does it in some way help scheduling threads on multicore machines?

I am specifially looking at whats with Task wrt multicore that wasnt there in 2.0 threads.

Comment: With TPL you don't need to write all that threading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could do everything equivalently in TPL or threadpool, for a better abstraction, and scalability patterns TPL is preferred over Threadpool. But it is upto the programmer, and if you know exactly what you are doing, and based on your scheduling and synchronization requirements play out in your specific application you could use Threadpool more effectively. There are some stuff you get free with TPL which you've got to code up when using Threadpool, like following few I can think of now.

- [work stealing](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/08/12/BuildingACustomThreadPoolSeriesPart2AWorkStealingQueue.aspx)
- [worker thread local pool](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2009/04/task-parallel-library-parallel.html)
- scheduling groups of actions like [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> "I agree Task simplifies the creation and use of threads"

Isn't that enough? Isn't it *fabulous* that it provides higher-level building blocks so that us mere mortals can build lock-free multithreaded code which is safe because *really* smart people like Joe Duffy have done the work for us?

If TPL really just consisted of a way of starting a new task, it wouldn't be much use - the work-stealing etc is nice, but probably not crucial to most of us. It's the building blocks *around* tasks - and in particular around the idea of a "future" - which provide the value. Do you really want to write `Parallel.ForEach` yourself? Do you want to want to work out how to perform partitioning efficiently yourself? I know that if *I* tried doing that, it would take me a long time and I'd certainly do a worse job of it than the PFX team.

Many of the advances in development haven't been about making it possible to do something which was impossible before - they've been about raising the abstraction level so that a problem can be solved *once* and then that solution reused. Do you feel the same way about the CLR itself? You could do the same thing in assembly yourself, obviously... but by raising the abstraction level, the CLR and C# make us more productive.

Answer (score 0):

The TPL lets you program in terms of Tasks not threads. Thinking of tasks solely as a better thread abstraction would be a mistake. Tasks allow you to specify the work you want to get executed not how you want the work executed (threads). This allows you to express the potential parallelism of your application and have the TPL runtime--the scheduler and thread pool--handle how that work gets executed. This means that the TPL will take a lot of the burden off you of having your application deal with ensuring the best perfromance on a wide variety of hardware with different numbers of cores.

For example, the TPL makes it easy to implement key several design patterns that allow you to express the potential parallelism of your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx

Like Futures (mentioned by Jon) as well as pipelines and parallel loops.

Comment: Your teched video - http://www.msteched.com/2010/NorthAmerica/ARC205 is just awesome.